# Including Entity Framework tooling in docker container

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using the [aspnetcore](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/aspnetcore/) docker image to run an ASP.NET Core application using EF Core. Running the application works, but I am unable to use any tooling.

Commands like `dotnet ef database update` fail.

Is it possible to run any `DotNetCliToolReference` tooling without the full SDK?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to run any DotNetCliToolReference tooling without the full SDK?

No. The logic to execute these tools lives in the SDK.

But, if you run this with `--verbose` on a machine with the SDK you'll see a line that looks like this:

```
dotnet exec ... ef.dll ...
```

You *can* run that command inside the container.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use DotNetCliToolReference on a production.

But you can do it in two ways.

By resolving DbContext service and calling `Database.Migrate()`

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>() 
                    .CreateScope()) 
        { 
            serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<DatabaseApplicationContext>() 
                .Database.Migrate(); 
        } 

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

Or directly by calling `Database.Migrate()` in DbContext class

```
    protected DatabaseApplicationContext()
    {
        Database.Migrate();            
    }

    public DatabaseApplicationContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
        Database.Migrate();
    }
```

I would recommend first option because migration is done only at application startup. But the second one will be called when DbContext is created (most likely at every request, if you keep default DbContext scope - as a Scoped service)